# Triggered Sends and Salesforce Sends and Service Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, servicecloud, triggered-send

I have a triggered send which is working fine but triggered sends from Marketing Cloud - which I have working - are not visible in Service Cloud so someone had suggested using Salesforce Sends instead but I'm not sure of the steps to make Salesforce Sends behave like a Triggered Send.

I've tried replacing the Triggered Send external key with the Salesforce Send external key and calling the API but that doesn't work. Have also tried inserting a row to the Salesforce Send Data Extension, thinking that might trigger the send but it doesn't.

I suspect the answer is quite simple but can't find it - any ideas!??!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Bot says this is difficult to understand but hopefully for anyone who knows the answer it isn't! In simple terms the question is how do you automate triggering a Salesforce Send (which is a specific type of send which can be configured in Marketing Cloud). The automating and triggering should essentially achieve the same end as a Triggered Send BUT to agents using Service Cloud Triggered Sends are not shown in a contacts Marketing History - hence using Salesforce Sends

Comment: Are you already calling the Triggered Send from SFSC? Is Journey Builder an option, which should make life easier here?

Comment: Too late for an edit - If I'm not mistaken, Salesforce Sends are used from inside Automation Studio (like User-initiated sends) meaning they are not meant to be called from external sources like a Triggered Send;

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think you're right Jonas in both cases, have now solved the problem by using the add to Journey via API approach - Journey sends being visible in Service Cloud so problem solved. Thanks :)